# Faster connection with database in android

Tags: java, android, mysql

It has been a long time that I am using php/json to connect to the database in android, but I hate the speed, I know by having a good server or faster libraries i can speed it up but this time I need a different way and faster one.

I was wondering if there is faster way to connect online mysql databse in android?

Comment: use firebase or mongo DB

Comment: my bad luck, firebase is not a choice for me because of the sanctions, But can u explain more about mongoDB? @VishalPatoliya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use google app engine  it most efficient it is easily integrated in android project and it is scalable and easy to use Read this.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/

Comment: forbidden for my country :((